# How to mount a bitlocker-encrypted image so that it can be decrypted with dislocker?

Tags: mount

For a forensic case at university I am given a **bitlockedImage.img** disk image. I am trying to mount it using the following command on my command line:

```
sudo mount [image location]/bitlockedImage.img ~/img -o loop,ro
```

However, I am given back the following error:

```
mount: /home/[user]/img: unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'.
```

I am quite stuck at this point, because I need to mount the image to a loopback device before I can use dislocker to decrypt the drive and make a workable image from that, so it can be loaded into Autopsy.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Bitlocker is a Windows term so what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: A search on this site shows several answers. This is one of them. https://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux

Comment: @David That is pertaining to a mounted drive. I am talking about an image.

Comment: I have not seen anything here or on the internet about mounting an image.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can simply hand your .img file to dislocker's -V (volume) flag to run your --recovery-password=PASS against. After that u get the dislocker-file which u can mount, pretty much like a regular dislocker operation on a connected encrypted drive.

Thanks to all that tried to contribute to the question.